# How to declare timestamp variable with default as current timestamp not working

Tags: db2-luw

In my stored procedure, I want to set as default timestamp the current time.
But I am running in a compilation error, but with additional `set`, it will work.

```
DECLARE VSTART TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP;
```

I got this exception:

```
  [Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  An unexpected token "CURRENT TIMESTAMP" was found following "ME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT".  Expected tokens may include:  "<literal>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.28.11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please tag your questions with the correct Db2 platform tag (db2-zos , db2-400, db2-luw) - sometimes the answer depends on this.

If your Db2-server is Db2-LUW (Linux/Unix/Windows) then you need two separate statements, because the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-compound-sql-embedded) specifies that the variable-declaration syntax allows defaults of constant values, or null. Hence, one statement to declare the variable, another to assign a varying value to that variable.

This is true for both forms of compound sql (compiled and inlined).

The syntax that you show `...TIMESTAMP with DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP` is valid in DDL, but not in compound SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following alternative method inside a stored procedure:

```
-- Declare a variable
DECLARE VSTART TIMESTAMP;

-- Set the variable's value to the current timestamp
SET VSTART = CURRENT TIMESTAMP;

-- Sample compound statement
BEGIN
  -- Your code here
END;
```